# How to persist data found in tables within a django template, in postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am scraping several sites and I show the data obtained in 6 tables within a django template.

[image]

My intention is to persist the data of the tables in postgresql, but I can not realize how to perform that task.

In principle I am trying to save the data from the second table.

For this I have created the models that I show below, as well as a view that is called: registroDivisaArgentina ().

The template is called quotes.html and within it, there are 6 tables.

I have tried to work with a class called: RegisterArgentineValues () within a forms.py file

**models.py**

```
class DivisasArgentina(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['CodigoDA']
    CodigoDA = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key = True)
    Texto_para_Reporte = models.CharField(max_length=70)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.Texto_para_Reporte)

class ValoresDivisasArgentina(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['Dia']
    DivisasArgentina = models.ForeignKey(DivisasArgentina, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    Dia = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    Hora = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    Compra = models.FloatField()
    Venta = models.FloatField()
    Variacion_dia_anterior = models.FloatField()
    ClaveComparacion = models.CharField(max_length=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {} - {}'.format(self.DivisasArgentina, self.Dia, self.ClaveComparacion)
```

**cotizaciones.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block contenido %}
<form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="tab1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Divisas en el Mundo</th>
                    <th>Valor</th>
                </tr> 
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                {%for element in cotiz_mun%}
                    <tr>
                        {% for key,value in element.items %}
                            <td> {{ value }} </td>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="tab2">
            <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Divisas en Argentina</th>
                        <th>Compra</th>
                        <th>Venta</th>
                    </tr> 
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        {%for element in cotiz_arg%}
                            <tr>
                                {% for key,value in element.items %}
                                    <td>{{ value }}  </td>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            <thead>
        {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="tab3">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Dolar Banco Nacion Argentina (Divisas)</th>
                    <th>Compra</th>
                    <th>Venta</th>
                </tr> 
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    {%for element in cotiz_exp%}
                        <tr>
                            {% for key,value in element.items %}
                                <td>{{ value }} </td>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="tab4">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4">Dolar Futuro en Argentina</th>
                </tr>        
                <tr>
                    <th>Mes 1</th>
                    <th>Mes 2</th>
                    <th>Mes 3</th>
                    <th>Mes 4</th>
                </tr> 
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    {%for element in cotiz_dol%}
                        <td>
                            {{ element.Valores}}
                        </td>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="tab5">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="3">Indicadores Varios - Tasa Libor</th>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                    <th>Libor a 1 Mes</th>
                    <th>Libor a 2 Mes</th>
                    <th>Libor a 3 Mes</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        {%for element in cotiz_lib%}
                            <td>
                                {{ element.Valores }}
                            </td>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>           
                </tbody>
        </table>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="tab6">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Indicadores Varios - Indice Merval y Oro</th>
                    <th>Valores</th>
                </tr> 
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        {%for element in cotiz_ind%}
                            <tr>
                                {% for key,value in element.items %}
                                    <td> {{ value }} </td>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                </tr>        
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="saveData">
        <br></br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Guardar Datos</button>
    </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
def mostrar_cotizaciones(request):
    cotiz_arg = json.loads(j_cotizaciones_argentina)
    cotiz_mun = json.loads(j_cotizaciones_mundiales)
    cotiz_exp = json.loads(j_cotizacion_export)
    cotiz_dol = json.loads(j_dolar_futuro)
    cotiz_ind = json.loads(j_indicadores)
    cotiz_lib = json.loads(j_libor)

    context = {'cotiz_mun': cotiz_mun,
               'cotiz_arg': cotiz_arg,
               'cotiz_exp': cotiz_exp,
               'cotiz_dol': cotiz_dol,
               'cotiz_ind': cotiz_ind,
               'cotiz_lib': cotiz_lib,
                }

    return render(request, 'cotizaciones.html', context)

def registrarDivisaArgentina(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formulario = RegistrarValoresDivisasArgentinas(request.POST)
        if formulario.is_valid():
            formulario.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/listadoValores')
    else:
        formulario = RegistrarValoresDivisasArgentinas()
    formulario.setup('Registrar', css_class="btn btn-success")
    return render(request, 'cotizaciones.html', {'formulario':formulario})
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import fla
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from fla.models import *

class RegistrarValoresDivisasArgentinas(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ValoresDivisasArgentina
        fields= [Compra, Venta]
```

I have done some tests, but none has given a favorable result. Someone can tell me how to process the data (in the views and forms) that are in the tables, to be able to store them in my postgres tables ?

Answer (score 0):

I do this kind of task very often, and I've found out that the combination of [ScraPy](http://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/) with [scrapy-djangoitem](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-djangoitem) is a very good combo to use here.

Good luck!